# Adjusting velocity range of note input on GarageBand iOS with MIDI controller

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, audio, garageband

I am trying to get the best possible results in the realm of note velocity with my keyboard MIDI controller in GarageBand. The keyboard itself is touch sensitive, but the velocity sensitivity is very basic and uneven.

I'm using a Samson Carbon 61 keyboard controller with GarageBand iOS, specifically on an iPad Mini.
The keyboard's "velocity curve" can be controlled via the hardware, but all the built-in options except for full velocity (touch sensitivity off) seem to be too quiet to be usable. You can get loud notes, but it requires you to really attack the keyboard.

Now, there is a "velocity slider" on the GarageBand interface that allows you to control the range of note velocity, ensuring that the note input won't be too loud or too quiet. But sadly, this seems to only affect the on-screen touchscreen keyboard on the iPad.

Is there a way to get GarageBand to control the velocity range of note input from the *MIDI controller?*

If not, is there another way to get the iPad to even out the uneven touch sensitivity from the controller without turning touch sensitivity off?

Comment: Could you recast this question to clarify? It sounds like you're using the term 'velocity' [which is the Note On value] where it feels like you mean Volume [CC7] or perhaps Expression [CC11].

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote the question to clarify that I really do mean velocity. I'm trying to get better results from the controller's touch sensitivity.